# A low-resource utility that makes a WIn10 toast when a network connection is disconnected

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to get a Windows notification/toast immediately after a network connection is disconnected.

What is the least-resource intensive way to run the below command (or something similar) constantly in the background without significantly slowing down my PC?

```PoS
if ((get-netconnectionProfile).Name | ?{$_ -notmatch "MySSID"}) {New-BurntToastNotification -Text "Warning:  MySSID Not Connected!"}
```

Comment: I used a timer in [this script](https://github.com/mossrich/PowershellRecipes/blob/master/TrayNetworkIndicator.ps1) to check periodically. Might try something like it.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping there was a solution like this. Very useful!